# sql query to find users with three or more months in debt

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a little app (PHP/MySQL) to manage condos. There's a `condos` table, `apartments` table, a `owners` table and a `account` table.

In the `account` table I have the fields `month_paid` and `year_paid` (among others).

Each time someone pays the monthly fee, the table is updated with the number of the month and the year.

Here's some sample table structure:

`condos` table:

```
+----+------------+---------+
| id | condo_name | address |
+----+------------+---------+
```

`apartments` table:

```
+----+----------------+----------+
| id | apartment_name | condo_id |
+----+----------------+----------+
```

`owners` table:

```
+----+--------------+------------+
| id | apartment_id | owner_name |
+----+--------------+------------+
```

`account` table:

```
+----+----------+----------+------------+-----------+
| id | owner_id | condo_id | month_paid | year_paid |
+----+----------+----------+------------+-----------+
```

So, if I have a record in account table like this, it means this owner paid August 2012:

```
+----+----------+----------+------------+-----------+
| id | owner_id | condo_id | month_paid | year_paid |
+----+----------+----------+------------+-----------+
|  1 |        1 |        1 |          8 |      2012 |
+----+----------+----------+------------+-----------+
```

What I would like to know is how to make a SQL query (using PHP) to get the owners with three or more months in debt or, in other words, owners that have not payed the fee for the last three months or more.

If possible, the data should be grouped by condo, like this:

```
CONDO XPTO:
Owner 1: 3 months debt
Onwer 2: 5 months debt

CONDO BETA
Owner 1: 4 months debt
Onwer 2: 6 months debt
```

Thanks

Comment: can you please add sample records with desired result aling with your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fix your account table. The `DROP COLUMN`s are optional, you might want keep them if they have dependencies.

```
ALTER TABLE account ADD COLUMN date_paid DATETIME;
UPDATE account SET date_paid = CONCAT(year_paid,'-',month_paid,'-01');
--ALTER TABLE account DROP COLUMN year_paid;
--ALTER TABLE account DROP COLUMN month_paid;
```

This is how you’d get your data. I used `LEFT OUTER JOIN`s in case you have any missing owner or condo records.

```
SELECT c.condo_name, 
o.owner_name, 
min(PERIOD_DIFF(DATE_FORMAT(now(), '%Y%m'), DATE_FORMAT(date_paid, '%Y%m'))) min_months_debt 
FROM account a
LEFT OUTER JOIN condos c ON (c.id = a.condo_id)
LEFT OUTER JOIN owners o ON (a.owner_id = o.id)
WHERE a.date_paid <= DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL -3 MONTH)
GROUP BY c.condo_name, o.owner_name
ORDER BY c.condo_name
```

P.S. The above only works for condo owners who have made at least one payment. If you want to see condo owners who have never paid then you’re going to have to associate condos with owners outside of the accounts table. Or perhaps you create an account record when you associate a condo with an owner, in which case you don’t have a problem.

Comment: this seems to be the way but I'm getting too many results. I guess it's because of the accounts table having all the months payed. If a owner paid january to march, there will be 3 rows in the table. This way I'm getting 6 results for this owner. Maybe a select distinct?

Comment: I think a GROUP BY might be better, but then you need to decide whether to do a max() or min() on the months_debt field.

Answer (score 4):

You need to write a query something like this:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    owners
JOIN
    account
ON
    owners.id = account.owners_id
WHERE
    CONCAT( account.year_paid , '-' , account.month_paid , '-01') <= DATE_ADD( NOW(), INTERVAL -3 MONTH );
```

Sadly that's about all I can give you with the information you have provided. If you could show more detailed table structure, I could help you out more.

Answer (score 1):

You are making it harder on yourself by storing it this way. Now you need to calculate the difference in months yourself. You cannot just check on months, because e.g. in january you also need to take the year into consideration.

```
SELECT *
FROM owners
JOIN account ON owners.Id=account.ownersId
WHERE (    
  account.year_paid = year(now)
  AND (
    month(now)-account.month_paid>=3
  )
) OR (
  account.year_paid = year(now)-1
  AND (
    month(now)>=3
    OR (
      account.month_paid - month(now) <= 10
      AND month(now) = 1
    )
    OR (
      account.month_paid - month(now) <= 11
      AND month(now) = 2
    )
  )
) OR (
  account.year_paid < year(now)-1
)
```

Better to just store the lastpaid time in a `datetime` collumn so you can use date functions.

Comment: Albeit much more complex that the other answers, this query will likely running the quickest. @hugo-delsing has avoided writing a where clause that executes functions on all records.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correct you have two different fields for moth and for year. Why?
If you had one field say `paid_date` this query would work for you

`SELECT owner_id from account WHERE NOW()>DATE_ADD(paid_date, INTERVAL 3 MONTH)`

If you can change fielfd then sorry. I hope this is helpful.

**UPD:**
Then I'd suggest you concatenation of two fields (`year` and `month`) in the query to make it look like real date in `YYYY-MM-DD` format and use it in `DATE_ADD` function instead of `paid_date` field

Comment: This would be great but as I said I inherited the code and database. Maybe I'll try to bulk change the table and add that datetime field, populating it automatically with the month and year...

Comment: You want to avoid where clauses that execute functions on all records. E.g.: `WHERE CONCAT( account.year_paid , '-' , account.month_paid , '-01') <= DATE_ADD( NOW(), INTERVAL -3 MONTH )`. That where clause asks mysql to perform a `CONCAT()` on every single record in the accounts table! Nor do you want to do: `WHERE NOW()>DATE_ADD(paid_date, INTERVAL 3 MONTH)` because that executes `DATA_ADD()` on every single account record. Indexes won’t help you. You really want to be able to write a where clause like this: `WHERE date_paid <= DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL -3 MONTH)`.

Comment: @paulgrav so, you sugest I create a new field (date type) and concatenate the month and year into it (like YYYY-MM-DD) like Ruslan Polutsygan said? This seems to be a fast and easy operation and I'm willing to do it if the results are the better ones.

Comment: Yeah, I think everyone is suggesting that you alter your table as @RuslanPolutsygan described. Just make sure you don’t perform a function on the date_paid column in your where clause, otherwise there’s little or no performance benefit.

Comment: @paulgrav: Sure I know that full table scaning must be avoided. The main idea of my post is that filtering by one properly typed field(DATE) is more convenient than by several integer fields. 
For sure OP shouldn't use field inside functions and have to use indexes.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
select o.owner_name,c.condo_name   from owners o join account a join condos c
on o.id=a.owner_id  and c.id =a.condo_id  where year(curdate())=a.year_paid 
and  a.month_paid<month(curdate())-3
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't seen any answers that actually produce what you are looking for.  The following calculates the months in debt by calculating the current month minus the most recent payment date.  It then concatenates the results into a string:

```
select c.condo_name, o.owner_name, 
       cast(YEAR(now)*12+MONTH(now)) - MAX(year_paid*12+month_paid) as varchar(255)), ' month(s) debt'
from account a join
     owners o
     on o.id = a.owner_id join
     condos c
     on c.id = a.condo_id
group by c.condo_name,, o.owner_name
order by 1, 2
```

If you want only delinquent payers, then add a `where` clause to the effect of:

```
where YEAR(now)*12+MONTH(now)) - MAX(year_paid*12+month_paid)  > 1
```

Because you don't have the day of the month of the payment, there are some borderline conditions you might miss.

Comment: your code makes sense but I can't make it to work. The where clause gives-me a `Invalid use of group function`